# My code for iterating GPS receiver location doesn't work

Tags: scripting, procedural-programming

This is a line of code i've utilised in order to iterate for GPS location i've tried to base it off this guys code,

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1445808/newton-raphson-method-in-gps?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

but it does not work and comes back with General::ivar  '0 is not a valid variable' also out Out[129]=-2. Is the desired solution wrong or like what is the problem here... here is the code i've used, please be nice and basic because i am very very new to this program or coding

General::ivar   '0 is not a valid variable' comes up in the jacobian section through stack trace thank you for the comment

```
(*desired solution*)
xx = 1; yy = 6.2; zz = 1; g = 0

(*Constants*)
x1 = 1; x2 = -1; x3 = -3; x4 = 2; y1 = 8.2; y2 = 8.2; y3 = 8.2; y4 = \
8.2; z1 = 1; z2 = -3; z3 = 3; z4 = -2
d1 = Sqrt[(xx - x1)^2 + (yy - y1)^2 + (zz - z1)^2] - 0.47 g;
d2 = Sqrt[(xx - x2)^2 + (yy - y2)^2 + (zz - z2)^2] - 0.47 g;
d3 = Sqrt[(xx - x3)^2 + (yy - y3)^2 + (zz - z3)^2] - 0.47 g;
d4 = Sqrt[(xx - x4)^2 + (yy - y4)^2 + (zz - z4)^2] - 0.47 g;

(*F=0 function*)
f1[x_, y_, z_, g] = 
  Sqrt[(xx - x1)^2 + (yy - y1)^2 + (zz - z1)^2] - 0.47 g - d1;
f2[x_, y_, z_, g] = 
  Sqrt[(xx - x2)^2 + (yy - y2)^2 + (zz - z2)^2] - 0.47 g - d2;
f3[x_, y_, z_, g] = 
  Sqrt[(xx - x3)^2 + (yy - y3)^2 + (zz - z3)^2] - 0.47 g - d3;
f4[x_, y_, z_, g] = 
  Sqrt[(xx - x4)^2 + (yy - y4)^2 + (zz - z4)^2] - 0.47 g - d4;

(*Jacobian matrix*)
J[x_, y_, z_, 
   g] = {{D[f1[x, y, z, g], x], D[f1[x, y, z, g], y], 
    D[f1[x, y, z, g], z], 
    D[f1[x, y, z, g], g]}, {D[f2[x, y, z, g], x], 
    D[f2[x, y, z, g], y], D[f2[x, y, z, g], z], 
    D[f2[x, y, z, g], g]}, {D[f3[x, y, z, g], x], 
    D[f3[x, y, z, g], y], D[f3[x, y, z, g], z], 
    D[f3[x, y, z, g], g]}, {D[f4[x, y, z, g], x], 
    D[f4[x, y, z, g], y], D[f4[x, y, z, g], z], D[f4[x, y, z, g], g]}};

(*Random first guess*)
rn = {3, 5, 6, 3};
Do[(*Itterate*)
  rn += -Inverse[
      J[rn[[1]], rn[[2]], rn[[3]], rn[[4]]]].{f1[rn[[1]], rn[[2]], 
       rn[[3]], rn[[4]]], f2[rn[[1]], rn[[2]], rn[[3]], rn[[4]]], 
      f3[rn[[1]], rn[[2]], rn[[3]], rn[[4]]], 
      f4[rn[[1]], rn[[2]], rn[[3]], rn[[4]]]};
  Print["Step ", i, " Solution = ", rn];, {i, 1, 4}];
```

Comment: You may have assigned a value to a symbol when it should not have had one. However, this is too much code to wade through. Try and isolate the problem yourself, then post the part that goes wrong. You want a minimal working example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @MarcoB thank you i've edited and mentioned that jacobian part seems to be the problem could you now take a look again please

Comment: Have you observed that your functions do not depend on teir arguments? For example `f1[x_, y_, z_, g] = 
  Sqrt[(xx - x1)^2 + (yy - y1)^2 + (zz - z1)^2] - 0.47 g - d1;` does not have any `x`, `y`, `z` on the right hand side.  But the real problem is that you call `D[f1[x, y, z, g], g]` later. Due to `g = 0` this evaluates to  `D[f1[x, y, z, 0], 0]` and that should ring a bell.

Comment: In addition to issues noted above, you will need actual values for the four distances `d1`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reversed engineered to get the distances for this example. They are the square roots of `{4,24,24,14}` respectively. I thought it might be useful to have an alternative method since, among other things, it shows that there are multiple solutions (so another satellite reading is needed to remove the ambiguity). I made the constants exact but really that was not necessary 9it helped for finding the distances given the expected solution).

We set up a system of polynomial equations, getting rid of the square roots.

```
x[1] = 1; x[2] = -1; x[3] = -3; x[4] = 2; y[1] = 82/10; y[2] = 82/10; 
y[3] = 82/10; y[4] = 82/10; z[1] = 1; z[2] = -3; z[3] = 3; z[4] = -2;

poly[j_] := (d[j] + 
     47/100*g)^2 - ((xx - x[j])^2 + (yy - y[j])^2 + (zz - z[j])^2)

polys = Table[poly[j], {j, 4}];
```

Now provide values for the distances and solve the system.

```
dvals = Array[d, 4];
vars = {xx, yy, zz, g};
soln = Select[
  vars /. NSolve[polys /. Thread[dvals -> Sqrt[{4, 24, 24, 14}]], 
    vars], Apply[And, Thread[Im[#] == 0]] &]

(* Out[1236]= {{1., 10.2, 1., 0.}, {1., 6.2, 1., 0.}} *)
```

So the y coordinate is not uniquely determined, we only know it is 2 units from 8.2. Well, in part this is because the satellite positions are collinear (which is bad for GPS purposes).

Which one an iterative method finds will depend on initial values of course.

When there is sufficient data to uniquely pin down the location (that is, five or more readings), the issue becomes one of an over-determined system. Often a RANSAC-type approach is useful. Take random subsets of four equations, solve, see which solutions are, to close approximation, common to all (or at least most, in case there is ill-conditioning in some subsets). Once one is determined, use it as a starting point in a local refinement step, minimizing a sum of squares to approximately solve the overdetermined system.

Comment: Thank you so much and you have done an amazing job but i have solved the problem through different method but your code seem amazing, the only problem is (which is still my fault for not mentioning in the initial question) i wanted it to be an iterative results so thats that but regardless thank you so much

Comment: I'm sure it can be done iteratively (no guarantee as to which solution it converges to) but only if the distances are given. Without them the iteration gets into trouble (My session claimed to be "Not Responding" for about two minutes). The reason is it gets into some very difficult formatting for the print part.

Comment: Yea several of my previous attempts do that, and i do apologise for not giving distances in earlier question, and your reverse engineering of my code to gain the distances are absolutely correct, perhaps you can help with my other question that i've posted please feel free to check it out as you seem really competent in Mathematica, again thank you for your attempt https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172190/coding-non-linear-least-squares-gps-iteration-with-steps-and-solutions-showing here is a link to my other question @Daniel Lichtblau

Answer (score 1):

```
    (*desired solution*)xx = 1; yy = 6.2; zz = 1; gg = 0

    (*Constants*)
    x1 = 1; x2 = -1; x3 = -3; x4 = 2; y1 = 8.2; y2 = 8.2; y3 = 8.2; y4 = \
    8.2; z1 = 1; z2 = -3; z3 = 3; z4 = -2
    d1 = Sqrt[(xx - x1)^2 + (yy - y1)^2 + (zz - z1)^2] - 0.47 gg;
    d2 = Sqrt[(xx - x2)^2 + (yy - y2)^2 + (zz - z2)^2] - 0.47 gg;
    d3 = Sqrt[(xx - x3)^2 + (yy - y3)^2 + (zz - z3)^2] - 0.47 gg;
    d4 = Sqrt[(xx - x4)^2 + (yy - y4)^2 + (zz - z4)^2] - 0.47 gg;

    (*F=0 function*)
    f1[x_, y_, z_, g_] = 
      Sqrt[(x - x1)^2 + (y - y1)^2 + (z - z1)^2] - 0.47 g - d1;
    f2[x_, y_, z_, g_] = 
      Sqrt[(x - x2)^2 + (y - y2)^2 + (z - z2)^2] - 0.47 g - d2;
    f3[x_, y_, z_, g_] = 
      Sqrt[(x - x3)^2 + (y - y3)^2 + (z - z3)^2] - 0.47 g - d3;
    f4[x_, y_, z_, g_] = 
      Sqrt[(x - x4)^2 + (y - y4)^2 + (z - z4)^2] - 0.47 g - d4;

    (*Jacobian matrix*)
    J[x_, y_, z_, 
       g_] = {{D[f1[x, y, z, g], x], D[f1[x, y, z, g], y], 
        D[f1[x, y, z, g], z], 
        D[f1[x, y, z, g], g]}, {D[f2[x, y, z, g], x], 
        D[f2[x, y, z, g], y], D[f2[x, y, z, g], z], 
        D[f2[x, y, z, g], g]}, {D[f3[x, y, z, g], x], 
        D[f3[x, y, z, g], y], D[f3[x, y, z, g], z], 
        D[f3[x, y, z, g], g]}, {D[f4[x, y, z, g], x], 
        D[f4[x, y, z, g], y], D[f4[x, y, z, g], z], D[f4[x, y, z, g], g]}};

    (*Random first guess*)
    rn = {3, 5, 3, 0.02};
    Do[(*Itterate*)
      rn += -Inverse[
          J[rn[[1]], rn[[2]], rn[[3]], rn[[4]]]].{f1[rn[[1]], rn[[2]], 
           rn[[3]], rn[[4]]], f2[rn[[1]], rn[[2]], rn[[3]], rn[[4]]], 
          f3[rn[[1]], rn[[2]], rn[[3]], rn[[4]]], 
          f4[rn[[1]], rn[[2]], rn[[3]], rn[[4]]]};
      Print["Step ", i, " Solution = ", rn];, {i, 1, 12}];
```

this code seems to work after correction from Henrik Schumacher, thank you all for such kind help :D
Also it gives iterative results :D